# Regional tags should be used where appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

This excellent book has a list of tags for the different regions (from a dialect perspective) should we also create tags and encourage their use where appropriate?

http://books.google.ch/books?id=83uNJHw7aM8C&pg=PA7&dq=contemporary+german+book+register&hl=en&ei=NNnkTan7PMae-QbXyryMDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=region&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Of course. In fact, we already have [bavarian](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bavarian), [austrian](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austrian), [swabian](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swabian). No need to stop at that. There's also the umbrella tag [dialects](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects).